# Why does Flutter doc ask you to use GlobalKey when creating Form instead of other types of keys?

Tags: flutter

According to flutter doc, https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation, it says the following.

> When creating the form, provide a GlobalKey.

However, `GlobalKey` doc says that this key is expensive and recommend developers to use other types of keys.

> consider using a Key, ValueKey, ObjectKey, or UniqueKey (instead of globalKey)

What is the merit of using `GlobalKey` for `Form`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are pretty self explanatory I think.

> GlobalKey: A key that is unique across the entire app.

And when you create a `Form` you want it to be unique, and using `GlobalKey` you can identify the form.

And docs warn you to avoid `GlobalKey` at multiple places, like if you are using a `ListView` and you assign every children `GlobalKey`, it is a bad approach, however there is no harm of using `GlobalKey` if you are using it carefully.

Comment: If I construct regular `Key` with an unique string in the app... 1. Would that be equivalent of using `GlobalKey`? 2. Would that be okay?

Comment: 1. No, that won't be equivalent to `GlobalKey`, because if you assign a widget `Key("unique_string")`, and later on if that widget is removed from the widget tree, you can still create another widget with above key without any issue, but with `GlobalKey`, you can't just do that, it is unique across the lifetime of your widget tree. If you try to assign same `GlobalKey` to 2 widgets, you'll get an exception for using same `GlobalKey` at 2 places. `GlobalKey` is very unique than other `Key`s.

Comment: Why should I better off identify my form in the first place? What could happen if I do not give my form a unique key?